# Is there a way to take the average of a particular time field by a particular group count rather than record count?

Tags: reporting

I have a report on a custom object **'Case Status History'** which captures the time of a case in particular Status. I have **'Time Elapsed'** field in the object which calculates the time in a Status. I have to create a report to calculate a particular persons average working time. Means if a case owner **'XYZ'** has worked upon **2 cases** and has changed status **3 times** then **3 'Case Status History'** records will be created for that owner. Now I want the **Avg(sum(Elapsed time in all status)/Number of cases worked by XYZ i.e 2)** . What I am getting now is **Avg(sum(Elapsed time in all status)/Number of Case Status History record count by XYZ i.e 3)**. Any way to achieve what I need ?

[image]